# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on Raspberry PI - MySQL was working and then stopped

Tags: server, mysql, raspberrypi

I have been using MySQL with Ubuntu 20.04.3 on Raspberry PI for about 3 months with absolutely no problem but earlier this week I discovered `mysql.service` was no longer running. As this is definitely only a development machine and I am doing all kinds of things whilst developing a webapp I assumed it was something I had done to screw it up. However, when investigating I quickly realised that `mysql.service` was starting and immediately failing -

```
Mar 23 21:48:16 magPIe mysql-systemd-start[2280]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
Mar 23 21:48:16 magPIe mysql-systemd-start[2280]: mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libprotobuf-lite.so.3.11.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After a lot of digging and searching (and learning) I first installed `libprotobuf-lite17` without effect but then found `libprotobuf-lite.so.3.11.4` in `/usr/lib/oldsql/private` - I created a symbolic link for the file in `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu` and hey presto was able to restart `mysql.service`. As I am only playing around with the system I should now be content - but as I am not aware of doing anything that would 'archive' the `.so` file and not aware of doing anything to suddenly create a need for the `.so` file I am curious about how the situation came about (and slightly worried that my 'fix' is inappropriate)...

... anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: OldSQL is a different project to MySQL, so I don't think "archive" is an accurate way of looking at the issue. You may want to look at the `/var/log/apt/history.log` file to see whether anything has been uninstalled recently which may have also removed the library in question. Your solution is certainly workable in the short term, but be aware that this can cause future updates to either MySQL or OldSQL to break the MySQL service once again 

Comment: Been there, done that (but only after posting). However, looking at history.log shows me just how many times I have uninstalled/reinstalled mysql in the last 4 weeks. I have today discovered more library files have gone 'walkabout' :( I have now come to the conclusion to just rebuild the server from scratch. Just as well I am only playing around! But thanks for the feedback! My problems probably started by trying to get my web app to send 'status' emails - without a FQDN.

Comment: If you regularly add and remove applications, then you may want to look at Docker containers. They have made situations like this a practical impossibility for me over the last couple of years. If I want to completely rebuild a MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, or other environment from scratch, it's just a simple `sudo docker start {thing}`, and I'm off and running. No more mucking about with partially-deleted files and straggling directories ...